# Is there a way to detect resize/zoom in all Ancestor DOM elements using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a DOM element which contains a chart

```
<div id="plot1" class='plot-chart'></div>
```

This DIV can be nested in multiple DIVs

```
<div id="one" style="width:100%;height:100%;zoom:0.9;">
    <div id="two">
        <div id="three">
            <div id="plot1" class='plot-chart'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need a way to detect any changes to size/zoom to all the ancestors(parents) of the plot DIV so I can zoom or resize it accordingly.

```
window.onresize
```

this works to detect any change to the overall browser window, but there maybe instances where DIV two or DIV three maybe changed without the window itself being manipulated. The Chart DIV is the one which I am creating and can be placed in any location, so calling a function from the outside when a resize happens is not a solution.

To simplify the question, is there any way to detect changes to any of the parent DIV's of my object so I can call a function internally?

Answer (score 0):

So the short answer is "no". However, if you have any control over the cases where those container divs would be resized, then *they* could trigger custom events, (for instance, [using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)) that your chart could listen to and react appropriately.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm trying to create a chart framework, so the chart object (DIV) would be unaware of its surroundings so triggering it externally is not something I can do.

Comment: Ok, well, then without help from the environment, you will have no other choice than polling - and that's never a good idea.

Comment: I went with a polling solution may not be elegant or efficient but it gets the job done without screwing up performance too badly.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can easily use Twitter's Bootstrap to do resizing.

You can use the [Grid System in BootStrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) for this!

Comment: This looks like a method to zoom/scale DIVs, I already have a custom zoom/resize method to handle my DIV. What I'm looking for is a way to trigger the zoom/resize on any changes to the parent DIVs.

Comment: You can't do this without the help from the surrounding environment. That is why there are frameworks that do automatic resizing without worrying about parent/ child divs.